# bootstrap button at the right hand side of h3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the code blow, depending on whether I use `display:inline-block` or not, the plus button is placed at top-right or bottom-right but never at the same line with `h3`.

What is the problem?

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/35253/

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="border: 1px solid">
  <h3 style="text-align: center;display:inline-block">aaaaaaaaaaa</h3>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-flat" style="float:right;"></span>
</div>


<div style="border: 1px solid">
  <h3 style="text-align: center;">bbbbbbbbb</h3>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-flat" style="float:right;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try increasing the line-height property of the icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want like this:

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div style="border: 1px solid">
  <h3 style="text-align:center; margin:0px; padding:10px 5px;">aaaaaaaaa
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-flat" style="float:right; position:relative; top:8px; font-size:15px;"></span></h3>
  </div>


  <div style="border: 1px solid">
  <h3 style="text-align:center; margin:0px; padding:10px 5px;">bbbbbbbbb
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-flat" style="float:right; position:relative; top:8px; font-size:15px;"></span></h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Placing the button inside the `h3` makes its size jumbo.

Comment: No problem give the font-size to span class.

Comment: @ar2015 I have changed the code according to your requirement. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `pull-right` class to your span and place it under `<h3>`. There are two results you can see in snippet.

1. When you use `style="display:inline-block;"`.
2. Normal `h3` without any style. `heading` has the by default property of `disply:block`.

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="border: 1px solid">
  <h3 style="display:inline-block;">aaaaaaaaaaa <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-flat pull-right" style="font-size:small;padding-top: 6px;"></span></h3>

</div>


<div style="border: 1px solid">
  <h3 class="text-center">bbbbbbbbb <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-flat pull-right" style="font-size: small; padding-top: 6px;"></h3>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: It would always be better to describe your answer...!

Comment: Thank you very much. Placing the button inside the `h3` makes its size jumbo.

Comment: I Updated my code. Hope now it's look like what you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: inline-block;` property in both tags.

```css
h3, span {display: inline-block;}
span {float: right; margin-top: 20px;} 
.glyphicon-plus::before {line-height: 30px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
  <h3>aaaaaaaaaaa</h3>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-flat"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it does not keep the center alignment.

Comment: Updated answer! Now both are in center.

Comment: can I have the `h3` at the center and yet the plus button at the right corner?

Comment: Updated answer once again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this HTML

HTML

```
    <div style="border: 1px solid; text-align:center;">
  <h3 style="text-align: center;display:inline-block">aaaaaaaaaaa</h3>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-flat"></span>
</div>


<div style="border: 1px solid; text-align:center;">
  <h3 style="text-align: center; display:inline-block;">bbbbbbbbb</h3>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-flat"></span>
</div>
```

Making the element `float`, removes the normal DOM flow. To align items center you need to remove `float` property and add `text-align:center` to the parent div

make use of line-height property on the span icon elements..

Hope this Helps..

Comment: How about the center alignment of `h3`?

Answer (score 1):

as you are using bootstrap.min.css you have predefined classes so simply apply the class to your code, for that see the snippet below, just ignore me if you are not agree with my post

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
   <div style="border: 1px solid">
      <h3>aaaaaaaaaaa<span class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-flat"></i></span></h3>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
   <div style="border: 1px solid">
      <h3>bbbbbbbbbbb<span class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-flat"></i></span></h3>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

add a class text-center  for h3 / entire div or  where ever you need this a bootstrap predefined class

Comment: How about the center alignment of `h3`?